# Bash, checking variable

Tags: bash, if-statement, echo

Ok, so I'm trying to run a script where if the user enters `y` or `Y`, then the output is `YES` but if the user inputs `n` or `N` then the output is `NO`, this is what I have so far:

```
read character
if (( ("$character") == "y" )) || (( ("$character" == "Y") )); then
echo "YES"
else
echo "NO"
fi
```

When I run this code I get `YES` successfully but inputting `n` just results in `YES` anyway.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and any I'd love some input.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`((...))` is used for math calculations. You can use `[[...]]` in BASH like this:

```
read character
if [[ "$character" == [yY] ]]; then
   echo "YES"
else
   echo "NO"
fi
```

Also I have combined 2 conditions into one using `[yY]` glob pattern.

Comment: `[yY]` is **also a glob pattern** that is matched by `==`